# Multiple relationships on composite foreign keys in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, relationship

I am trying to create an edge type class to link two nodes. Each of the nodes is a class by itself and both nodes and edge should be part of the same graph. I keep getting

```
Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship TypeiNode.edges - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.
```

even though the foreign keys are defined. I tried defining foreign keys on the node table `edges` relationship but got the same result. Can someone tell me what is wrong with this example.

```
class Edge(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'edge'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    graph_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('graph.id'))
    graph= relationship('Graph', back_populates='graph_edges')
    type_1_node_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('type_1_node.id'))
    type_1_node = relationship('Type1Node',
                               back_populates='edges',
                               foreign_keys=[type_1_node_id, graph_id])
    type_2_node_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('type_2_node.id'))
    type_2_node = relationship('Type2Node',
                               back_populates='edges',
                               foreign_keys=[type_2_node_id, graph_id ])
    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['type_1_node_id', 'graph_id'],
            ['type_1_node.id','type_1_node.graph_id']),
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['type_2_node_id', 'graph_id'],
            ['type_2_node.id','type_2_node.graph_id']),
    )    

class Type1Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'type_1_node'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    graph_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('graph.id'))
    graph = relationship('Graph', back_populates='graph_1_nodes')
    edges = relationship('Edge', back_populates='type_1_node')

class Type2Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'type_2_node'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    graph_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('graph.id'))
    graph = relationship('Graph', back_populates='graph_2_nodes')
    edges = relationship('Edge', back_populates='type_2_node')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the error carefully, you'll notice it's not complaining about the relationships that you added the `foreign_keys` argument to, but the ones you didn't:

```
Could not ... on relationship **TypeiNode.edges** ...
```

I take

> I tried defining foreign keys on the node table edges relationship but got the same result.

to mean that you did not try defining both ends at the same time. So the solution is to define the foreign keys in both ends:

```
class Type1Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'type_1_node'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    graph_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('graph.id'))
    graph = relationship('Graph')
    edges = relationship('Edge', back_populates='type_1_node',
                         foreign_keys=[Edge.type_1_node_id, Edge.graph_id])
```

Comment: Thanks @Ilja Everilä, That worked. I do however get warnings, of the form SAWarning: relationship    `Edge.type_1_node' will copy column type_1_node.graph_id to column edge.graph_id, which conflicts with relationship(s): 'Edge.graph' (copies graph.id to edge.graph_id). Consider applying viewonly=True to read-only relationships, or provide a primaryjoin condition marking writable columns with the foreign() annotation.`. Is there a better way to construct this Node-Edge-Graph relationship scheme?